# symfony services.yml does not contain valid YAML

Tags: symfony

I get an error in my services.yml : services.yml does not contain valid YAML
**Symfony 3**

```
redirectionListener:
  class: Gba\GbaBundle\Listener\RedirectionListener
  arguments: [@service_container, @session] 
  tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Can you help me

Thanks

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Now that is a long error message!  You need to use quotes around strings containing the @ symbol '@session'.  It used to work without the quotes so if you are following an example without quotes then discard the example as it is old and outdated and will probably have other issues as well.

Answer (score 5):

There are some restrictions in yaml you have to be aware of. Symfony has a neat command line tool you can use to check if a yaml file is valid that will also try to point you to where the error lies. You can run it like this:

```
bin/console yaml:lint src/Gba/GbaBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
```

This will only do the lint on this one file you can also point it to a whole directory of files if you want.

My best guess is, that you have to put quotes around the services defined as arguments and in fact I prefer to quote every string value in yaml:

```
redirectionListener:
  class: 'Gba\GbaBundle\Listener\RedirectionListener'
  arguments: ['@service_container', '@session'] 
  tags:
    - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'kernel.request', method: 'onKernelRequest' }
```

Other things to look out for in yaml is correct indentation and mixing spaces & tabs.

Answer (score 1):

I linted my yml on this website. Helped me find the error ASAP.

https://yamlchecker.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had this error once. It was because I didn't let a blank line at the end of my services.yaml file.
Once I did so, no more errors !

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to having blanks at the end of the line after the } symbol.